# Unable to Display CupertinoDialog in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have the following code to display Cupertino AlertDialog but I keep getting an error:

```
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: Text("Attention"),
        content: Text(this),
        actions: [
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            isDefaultAction: true,
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Here is the error I keep getting

```
Unhandled Exception: No MaterialLocalizations found.
```

I thought CupertinoAlertDialog has nothing to do with MaterialApp, so why do I keep getting this error.

The parent app here is  a CupertinoApp.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ShowDialog displays a Material dialog above the current contents of the app, with Material entrance and exit animations, modal barrier color, and modal barrier behavior (dialog is dismissible with a tap on the barrier).

So, Basically to show a Cupertino dialog you can use

```
showCupertinoDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(),
    );
```

Comment: You are the Boss! That worked. Thank you.